# MyBatis ResultMap Association Java Api

Tags: java, api, associations, mybatis

I am referring to this section in the documentation of mybatis:
https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Nested_Results_for_Association

I have a table row that contains information about two entities (A, B). I want to parse one entity and associate the other entity to the first:

```
public class A {
    int id;
    String name;
    B b;
}

public class B {
    long number;
    String description;
}
```

I can see that I do that via xml and two resultMaps where one is associated with the other over the association-Tag.

How do I do the same thing with the Java Api?

My first try resulted in an exception:

```
@Results( value = { ..., @Result(property = "prop", javaType = B.class, one = @One(resultMap = "de.mycompany.path.to.ClassADao.resultMapId")) })
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No typehandler found for property prop
```

Edit: I fully-qualified the path to resultMap in the One-Annotation.

Comment: There are some [tests](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/395be63314d77cf5b956a77631ab0620de26df7a/src/test/java/org/apache/ibatis/submitted/annotion_many_one_add_resultmapid/UserDao.java) in the repo. If you need further assistance, please create and share a small demo project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) and share it on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an old version of mybatis (3.5.3). The feature that I was missing came in this commit: https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/commit/e05d686bf8bb5b0d7c319a117e47e77e969880cb#diff-07ec4f0ed5561eb9a977945899598048e355554d0fa2e50f173e525e6b8f3574

Which is available from 3.5.5 onwards. I upgraded to 3.5.7.